# LogParser Error: Syntax Error: extra token(s) after query: 'Files\Apache'

Tags: apache, logparser

I am trying to run LogParser to dump all contents from access.log into an equivalent CSV file:

```
C:\Program Files\Log Parser 2.2>LogParser "select * into foo.csv from C:\Program  Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs\access.log" -i:ncsa -o:csv
```

However, I keep getting this error: **Error: Syntax Error: extra token(s) after query: 'Files\Apache'** and I am unsure of whether I am missing more syntax or I have some format wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add single quotes around the source log file (if the path has any empty spaces in it).

```
LogParser "select * into foo.csv from 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs\access.log'" -i:ncsa -o:csv
```

Comment: Same error may occur when your logfile is "chosen" from a path whose name includes certain characters that Log Parser Studio "doesn't like'. I just moved my log file to my "c:\temp\" and "chose" that file. Now all is well. This answer focused me on the right area - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with log parser, but judging from the error, your query is terminating at the first space.
The site: http://misigah.com/?p=28 mentions using "\u0020" for spaces within a query column.  Following that guidance, your query would be:

*LogParser "select * into foo.csv from C:\Program\u0020Files\Apache\u0020Software\u0020Found...*

There is also 2 spaces between "Program" and "Files".

Hope that helps

Comment: The extra space did give me a slightly different error, but that was a good catch. However, adding those hardcoded spaces you mentioned did not help. I got a new error: **Cannot open <from-entity>: Error opening files: Error searching for files in
  folder C:\Programu0020Files\Apacheu0020Softwareu0020Foundation\Apache2.2\logs: The system cannot find the path specified.**

Comment: Note: In Log Parser 2.2, you can also use single quotes to delimit the FROM clause. So beginning in 2.2 you can say "SELECT * FROM 'Copy of MyFile.csv'"  This is taken from the website: http://forums.iis.net/p/1155654/1895114.aspx